# Evaluating the integral of $\int \frac{\cos x }{4 + \sin^2 x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate the integral $$\int \frac{\cos x }{4 + \sin^2 x} dx$$

the quotient confuses me, I guess I need to use trig identities but still cannot solve it. Substutution seems to be useless here.

Hints are very appreciated

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $u = \sin x$ then $du = \cos x\  dx$ and $$\int \frac{1}{4 + u^2} du = \frac{1}{4}\int \frac{1}{1 + \big(\frac{u}{2}\big)^2} du $$

It is a known integral.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Set $\sin x=u\implies\cos x\ dx=du$

Then use $\dfrac{d(\arctan x/a)}{dx}=\dfrac1a\dfrac1{1+(x/a)^2}=\dfrac a{a^2+x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for hints, but in case you are curious to see the full solution, here is one of the ways you can try to solve it.

We use the following substitution
$$\sin x=2u\quad \cos xdx=2du$$
Applying the substitution and knowing that $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $u=\frac{1}{2}\sin x$ (this one is from our substitution), we get
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{2}{4+4u^2}du&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{1+u^2}du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\arctan u+c\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{\sin x}{2}\right)+c}
\end{align*}
Hope it helps! :)